# Как сделать чтобы цикл for передавал случайное количество значений из списка

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть цикл `for` который передает все значения списка `links100` (в списке цифры для наглядности, может быть все что угодно). Как дописать цикл чтобы он возвращал случайный процент (в диапазоне от 60% до 80%) значений списка `links100`. В результате значения списка должны идти по-порядку.
Пример ответа: `1 2 3 5 6 8 10`

```py
import random

def get_result(result):

    print(result)

def main():

    links100 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

    for i in links100:
        result = i
        get_result(result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import random


def get_result(result):
    print(result)

def main():

    links100 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

    num_samples = round(len(links100) * random.uniform(0.6, 0.8))

    rand_mask = [1] * num_samples + [0] * (len(links100) - num_samples)
    random.shuffle(rand_mask)

    for (i, is_chosen) in zip(links100, rand_mask):
        if is_chosen:
            result = i
            get_result(result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Как-то сложно :) `sorted(random.sample(links100, num_samples))`.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов, ну, в принципе да, наверное автор именно это и хотел под словами "значения должны идти по порядку". Но я читал не внимательно и понял так, что для выбранных элементов должен сохранятся тот же порядок, что и в исходном массиве, и код сочинял именно под такую формулировку :))